# Attaching a Wii cable to old laptop power brick wire colors

Tags: wii

My Wii power brick is burned And I want to connect the DC wire to an old laptop power brick I have lying around.
The Wii's brick has AC 120V input at 52W and 60Hz, and an output of DC12V 3.7A

The laptop's brick runs at AC 115/230V input at 1.2A, 47-63Hz and output of 10V,  2.8A.

My problem lies in the color of the wires in the laptop brick's  DC cable. The colors are red,  orange,  yellow,  black, grey,  green,  and tan. There are no colors in the Wii's DC cable (that plugs directly into the Wii) other than black and white

How would I connect these two?

[image] [image]

Comment: The laptop PSU isn't powerful enough to run the Wii -  buy a proper one.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have another one that runs at 18.5V and 2.2 A but I don't think that will work either

Comment: @Tetsujin I also have an Xbox 360 PSU but I use it so I'm not sure if I would be able to splice them together

Comment: correct - so just buy one that will, there's less chance of burning the house down :/

Comment: Just cut the red wire ^^